# Could you please find below details VS Please find below details

Tags: business-language, could

I am writing a business email providing details that customer has requested...

Below are two versions...

1. Please find below attached details.
2. Could you please find below attached details.

Could someone please explain the difference between above two?

Comment: One is an instruction, and one is a request. Both need smoothening: Please see the attached details. The word *below* cannot precede its noun, but you could say *details below* or *list below*.

Comment: Traditionally, _please find enclosed_ was a polite way of telling the recipient of a letter that you had enclosed another document in the envelope, just in case they missed it. You can just as well say _I enclose X_ or _X is enclosed_. I don't think anyone ever used _Could you please_, as it's not really a request.

Comment: "Could you please ...." (eg "Could you please return the book I lent you, Jill.") is a polite request (not a question, hence no question mark) which would be used commonly in conversation, and in a personal communication in print where there is a degree of familiarity, but never in a totally impersonal communication (as here) / set of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

**Main focus of question:** When using "please" to soften an imperative sentence, *please* alone is enough, in modern usage:

> Please consult the owner's manual.

Adding "Could you" threatens to turn the sentence into a question, and makes what had been a distanced, generic recommendation into a personal request. Of course, if you *are* making a direct request, feel free:

> Could you please look over the attached documents and get back to me?

---

**Other issues with the example**:

1. It would be unlikely to use "attached" and "below" together in this way. "Attached" means additional documents delivered at the same time—perhaps literally "attached," i.e. stapled or paper-clipped, or else the term is extended to other pages included loose in the same envelope, or to email attachments. "Below" suggests that the information can be found on the same page and screen (for an email, meaning in the body of the email). Note that various email clients might display email attachments differently; the recipient might find them at the top for all you know.
2. You probably want to switch the word order so that "attached" is not merely descriptive but locative: "You'll find the details attached."
3. For similar reasons, as Yosef noted, the preposition *below* needs to come after the noun (and "attached," if it's also been moved after the noun): "You'll find the details attached below."